# Storing an SQLite database file in TFS and the -journal file

Tags: android, sqlite, tfs

I have a pre-populated, read only SQLite database file I am shipping as an Asset with my Android App. Changes to the read only data constitute a version release/update in the app store. Thus, the DB file (and currently the journal file) are being stored in version control (TFS).

The question:

Is there any advantage to storing the -journal file in version control? After everything I read about SQLite, my understanding is it is basically just a simple transaction log for a file and there's no database engine in play (like with MSSQL Server). In effect, TFS is keeping my read only data Versioned, so I see no reason to check-in the journal file or have it be part of my project / assets at all. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is not a transaction that has not yet been committed or rolled back, the journal file is empty.
So it should never be required to have it in version control.

(The default [journal mode](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode) is DELETE, so unless you have changed this setting, you should investigate how this file ended up in TFS in the first place.)

Comment: Aside from not "required" I'm going to now say, maybe it's in fact very problematic. Aside from causing my initial confusion as to when / how the file is maintained: The initial reason for my question was due to a corrupted journal which had to be deleted in order to even open the db. Now I'm guessing the issue was in fact caused by having a journal file locked up in TFS / unable to be edited by SQLite. Though I'm not 100% sure how it occurred, there seems to be no other explanation for the corruption but the file in TFS was NOT empty and the default had not changed.